# How to append an object to an array based on the number of properties other than the specified properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For example , I have an array of objects like so :

```
[

{
      "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 1",
      "Deaths":-2333,
      "Births":8786,
      "open":0,
      "close":6453
   },
   {
      "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 2",
      "Deaths":-1000,
      "Births":5000,
      "open":0,
      "close":10453
   },
   {
      "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 3",
      "Deaths":-2000,
      "Births":500,
      "open":0,
      "close":8953
   }
]
```

I want to add two(does not have to be two,if there is a `"Extra Births"` then three) intermerdiate objects between each population like so

```
[

{
      "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 1",
      "Death":-2333,
      "Births":8786,
      "open":0,
      "close":6453
   },
   {
      "Deaths" : -1000,
       "open"   : 6453,
       "close"  : 5453
   },
   {
     "Births" : 5000,
      "open"   : 5453,
      "close   : 10453
   }
   {
      "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 2",
      "Deaths":-1000,
      "Births":5000,
      "open":0,
      "close":10453
   },
   {
      "Deaths" : -2000,
      "open"    : 10453,
      "close"   : 8453
   },
   {
      "Births" : 500,
      "open"    : 8453,
      "close"   : 8953
   }
   {
      "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 3",
      "Deaths":-2000,
      "Births":500,
      "open":0,
      "close":8953
   }
]
```

So as you can see I want to add objects based on the number of properties other than the `waterfallData.PopulationName` ,`open` and `close` properties. Then, I want to assign `open` and `close` properties on each object based on the next `"Deaths"` and `"Births"` values.

For example , `Population 1` starts with 6453 then I add two objects with the 1st object taking the next `"Deaths"` value in `Population 2` which is -1000 then I assign the `open` property to be from the previous `close` property of `Population 1` and the `close` property to be calculated by adding the assigned `open` property to `"Deaths"`'s value. And same goes with the 2nd extra object where I assign the `open` property to be the `close` property of the previous object and the `close` property to be calculated by adding `open` with `"Births"`'s value.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why not create using nested JSON?

Comment: @HymnZ because I am using Amcharts and it does not support nested JSON data.

Comment: You can try with Object.keys(your_array[1]) to create extra properties.. Just as @Grégory NEUT answered

Comment: NB: your target structure is a bad idea. It would be more logical to add an array *inside* each object having the content you describe. Also, property names with sequence numbers in them (`State 1`, `State 2`) indicates a bad design.

Comment: NB2: object properties are unordered, so the concept of *"the number of properties after..."* is unreliable. All you could say is *"the number of properties other than..."*.

Comment: @trincot edited my question accordingly. Unfortunately Amcharts does not support nested arrays so I have to make it flat. Any ways around this on your mind?

Comment: Usually a question should include what you've tried. I will give you a hint on solving this with a method called zip: `const zip = (arr1, arr2) =>  [...new Array(Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length))]    .map((_, i) => i).map((i) => [arr1[i], arr2[i]]);` You can zip your array into an array with [current,next] elements like so `zip(arr,arr.slice(1))` Then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) it to the desired output. Please let us know if you get stuck giving this a try.

Comment: Did you consider using the `lodash` library? You have a lot of methods there the manipulate arrays, you can differentiate, intersect, concatenate and much mor with custom operators and such

Comment: Hey, no cheating. You changed the question from using properties such as 'State [Number]' to 'deatsh' and 'biths'.  Trincot's deleted answer had a comment where he states that Object.keys is not to be guaranteed to come in any particular order so how will you know what's next and previous?

Comment: @HMR Well for one , as trincot himself says , property names with sequence in them indicates a bad design so I changed it . And another, I don't need to know wha'ts next or previous. All I need is for it to exclude the waterfallData.populationName,open and close properties.

Comment: So you went from dynamic amount of properties 'State [number]' to fixed amount `Deaths` and `Births`?

Comment: @HMR No it is still dynamic, This is just an example. The number of properties is based on user input. Deaths and Births are just examples.

Comment: If Deaths and Births are dynamic then in what order do these dynamic properties need to be processed? You say order is not important but then state in your question that deaths comes before births

Comment: @HMR can be either way. Does not matter. I do not mind a solution that ignores the order.

Comment: @HMR.. How does the order matter? OP has indicated how the calculations work and that is dependent on the field name rather than the order.

Comment: @SyedAriff .. Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Open is value of *previous* close, so yea... order matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude.. but works

```
var newArr = [];
$x = [{
    "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 1",
    "Deaths":-2333,
    "Births":8786,
    "open":0,
    "close":6453
},{
    "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 2",
    "Deaths":-1000,
    "Births":5000,
    "open":0,
    "close":10453
},{
    "waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 3",
    "Deaths":-2000,
    "Births":500,
    "open":0,
    "close":8953
}];
$x.forEach((p,i)=>{
    var current = $x[i]
    newArr.push(current)
    try {
        var next = $x[i+1];
        var start = current.open;
        var end = current.close;
        var states = Object.keys(current).sort().filter((k)=>{return (['waterfallData.PopulationName','open','close'].indexOf(k) < 0)})
        for (var i=0;i<states.length;i++){
            var state = states[i]
            var tempObj = {}
            tempObj[states[i]] = next[states[i]]
            tempObj['open'] = end;
            end += next[states[i]];
            tempObj['close'] = end;
            newArr.push(tempObj)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
})
```

The code will look for all properties other than waterfallData.Popu..,open,close and treats them as states. If you have 10 properties, there will be 7 states excluding the above 3. Then the open and close values of these states are then calculated from the next element and pushed to new array newArr.

Comment: what is $x? It says ReferenceError $x is not defined.

Comment: @SyedAriff .. a line got missed.. edited and updated.

Comment: Now try to run your code where you switch the order of `Deaths` and `Births` in the `$x` data: `$x = [{...
    "Births":8786,
    "Deaths":-2333` The output will differ

Comment: The point is that the output of your code relies on [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (look at the first line) to return the keys in a specific order but this is not the case. The specification says that there is [no guaranteed order of the keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties).

Comment: @HMR.. obviously, because by switching order of births & deaths, your representation itself changes.. to make it standardized.. I've added a sort to ensure consistency in the order.

On a side note, where can I learn to code minimally like you. :) It's glorious.. :D

Comment: The point was that `Object.keys` can give keys in a different order and that will change your output. In other words; if order is important then do not use object but use Map, Set or Array. The code I use relies heavily on functions doing only one thing and combining them, writing [pure functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976) and using the [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) methods `map`, `reduce`  and in this case `concat` and `flatten`

Comment: To write small (one OP functions) you can use arrow function syntax without a body: `argument=>result` instead of `argument=>{return result;}`. Code also relies on destructoring: `const myFunction = ([top, bottom])=>` You have to call myFunction with array: `myFunction([10,1])` Or object destructuring: `const myFunction = ({top,bottom})=>` then you can call it with an object `myFunction({top:10, bottom:1})` A good book would probably be [this one](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/README.md#you-dont-know-js-es6--beyond)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try, you can specify what keys you need to be extra data but the original data must have values for those keys. It'll create the extra items in the order that the keys are provided:

```js
const data = [{"waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 1","Deaths":-2333,"Births":8786,"open":0,"close":6453},{"waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 2","Deaths":-1000,"Births":5000,"open":0,"close":10453},{"waterfallData.PopulationName":"Population 3","Deaths":-2000,"Births":500,"open":0,"close":8953}];

const zip = (arr1, arr2) =>
  [...new Array(Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length))]
    .map((_, i) => i)
    .map((i) => [arr1[i], arr2[i]]);
const extras = (keys) => ([current, next]) =>
  keys.map((key) => [key, next[key]]).reduce(
    ([result, lastClose], [key, nextValue]) => [
      result.concat({
        [key]: nextValue,
        open: lastClose,
        close: nextValue + lastClose,
      }),
      nextValue + lastClose,
    ],
    [[], current.close],
  )[0];
const withExtras = (keys) => ([current, next]) =>
  !next
    ? [current]
    : [current].concat(extras(keys)([current, next]));
console.log(
  zip(data, data.slice(1)) //having [[current,next],[current,next]...]
    .map(withExtras(['Deaths', 'Births']))
    .flatten(),
);

console.log(
  'diffenrent order different result',
  zip(data, data.slice(1))
    .map(withExtras(['Births', 'Deaths']))
    .flatten(),
);
```